# How to add a Windows 7 to grub2

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu and Windows 7(windows first).
After that I can't boot into Windows.

> sudo update-grub2
>   Not see Windows.(but file explorer see this partition).

I add to /etc/grub.d/40_custom

```
menuentry ‘Windows 7′ {
set root=’(hd0,4)’
chainloader +1
}
```

And after that update-grub2, but when I restart my computer grub isn't starting(starts ubuntu).

```
fdisk -l
Urządzenie Rozruch   Początek      Koniec   Bloków   ID  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       11077    88969217    5  Rozszerzona
/dev/sda4           11077       19457    67317760    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda5               1       11077    88969216   83  Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend *boot-repair* for these tasks.

Steps:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Execute the following commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install boot-repair
   sudo boot-repair
   ```
3. Click *Advanced Options* if you want to customize anything or *Recommended reapir for the defaults*.

   By default, boot-repair will re-install GRUB to all available drives (handy if any of them goes bad) and add items for all found operating systems. It will also send statistics of use (can be disabled in *Other options* column).
4. Follow further instructions (if any).
5. Close boot-repair and reboot.